# Using Prettier for formatting .ejs files in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ejs, prettier

I want to use prettier for formatting my ejs files by adding custom rules.

Right now I am using files associations of html for ejs files.

I have added the following code in the settings.json file:
"files.associations": {
    "*.ejs": "html"
  },

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately Prettier does not currently support EJS. The list of supported languages are listed in their docs https://prettier.io/docs/en/index.html

However, they do support plugins so someone could add support https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html

Comment: I need whatever mojojs uses for templates `.html.tmpl`

Answer (score 2):

Very late to the party, I know, but I have just installed this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=j69.ejs-beautify, added the necessary properties to the settings.JSON file and upon reload, it works beautifully.

EDIT
This now formats the EJS file, with all indentation correct, resulting in a much easier to read and edit EJS file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).